# Passing values from csv to a selenium driver script in jmeter

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I am using selenium web driver sampler inside Jmeter.

I wrote the selenium script to login to a website. When I run the script using the hardcoded user email and password, it is working properly. Now I want to run 5 user Emails and passwords from CSV. In jmeter I know we can use CSV data config in case of HTTP sampler, but how can I pass 2 variables (useremail and password) to a web driver sampler. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

[WebDriver wiki](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) describe the two options to pass variables:

> Parameters - is optional and allows the reader to inject variables used in the script section.
>
> WDS.vars `<a href="../api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html">JMeterVariables</a>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given you define credentials as `username` and `password` in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config):

[image]

There are at least 2 possibilities:

1. Use "Parameters" section and pass JMeter Variables there (separated by whitespace), first parameter you can get as `WDS.args[0]`, second as `WDS.args[1]`, etc

   [image]
2. Use `WDS.vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, this way you will be able to access `${username}` JMeter variable as `WDS.vars.get('username')`, `${password}` JMeter Variable as `WDS.vars.get('password')`, etc.

   [image]

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)